# Binary Search Tree Printing a 3 way tree InOrder traversal

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Each node has two data,and 3 references to left,middle,right

My `insert` method will insert in sorted order,

```
left is less than
middle if in between
right if greater than

           6,10
        /    |   \  
      2,3    8    12,24
```

This is how far I have got (I understand how a regular binary traversal works) Im having trouble with the the 3-way traveral

```
  //Passing in the root node
 private void printing( BinaryNode t )
    {
        if( t != null )
        {
            printTree( t.left );
            printTree(t.middle);
            System.out.println(t.firstElement+" "+t.secondElement);              
            printTree(t.right);

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is more of a 2-3 tree than a binary search tree. Considering `firstElement > left && firstElement < middle`, you should probably also output it between left and middle...

Comment: thanks I was able to solve it